# Upgrading wifi card killed m.2 e key slot

Tags: linux, windows-10, hardware-failure, wifi-configuration, m.2

I tried upgrading my intel wireless-ac 7265 to a ax200ngw and only bluetooth worked. After swapping them back, still only bluetooth worked, when wifi was working before.

The wifi half of the cards do not appear in device manager in windows 10 or in the output of lspci in fatdog64, but bluetooth appears in device manager and lsusb, leading me to believe I killed my pcie (but not the usb) m.2 e key slot.

Please help me restore wifi functionality.

The computer is a [Hp probook x360 11 G1 EE](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05350661)

I have pentium n4200, 8gb ram and touchscreen version.

Comment: Try to reinstall the WLAN Driver. In this [page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-x360-11-g1-ee-notebook-pc/13414389) click on Driver-Network, then download and install the Intel WLAN Driver (21.40.2.2 Rev.L)

Comment: @spike_66 no dice.

Comment: Your notebook should have two USB 3.1 ports. Maybe you can dedicate one to a WiFi adapter. Or you could try to reset the OS

Comment: @spike_66 I do have a usb adapter in right now, but I don't want to *need* it. I'd much rather use the internal wifi, and the internal wifi is more reliable than my usb wifi dongle. And I already tried reinstalling windows 10, but the problem seems to be OS-independent.